# RemoteBuild giving deploy 404 when building from VS2017 and xcode 7.3.1

Tags: xcode, cordova, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-cordova, cordova-ios

I am trying to deploy cordova application using VS2017 and Xcode 7.3.1. The app builds fine but gives Deploy 404 error while deploying. The output stack is below:

```
------ Downloading completed build files from http://10.102.190.66:3000/cordova/build/78879/download to C:\MyApp\MyAppDemo\bld\iOS\Debug
------ Done downloading the build outputs to C:\MyApp\MyAppDemo\bld\iOS\Debug
------ Extracting the build outputs to C:\MyApp\MyAppDemo\bin\iOS\Debug
------ Done extracting the build outputs to C:\MyApp\MyAppDemo\bin\iOS\Debug
------ Copying back to project: ios
2>------ Deploy started: Project: MyAppDemo, Configuration: Debug iOS ------
2>Requesting deploy on remote iOS device for buildNumber 78879 on server http://10.102.190.66:3000/cordova...
2>http://10.102.190.66:3000/cordova/build/78879/deploy The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
```

Any suggestions are in fixing this are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've given up on using the remotebuild agent to build for iOS as this was broken many versions back and you cannot return to an obsolete API.

Instead, I'd suggest creating a mirrored copy of your project in your Mac, I know it will take more time to setup but this is the only approach that actually works.

To create and then update the app with this method, read the instructions here: [**Build Cordova iOS app from Visual Studio for Windows**](https://www.andreszsogon.com/build-cordova-ios-app-from-visual-studio-for-windows/)